# Don't understand this IndexError

Tags: python, numpy

I tried running this code

```
import numpy as np 
X=[]
j=0
a=np.array([1,-8,-9,2,5,8,7,1,-5,-5,1])
S=np.array([4,8,9,8,9,55,6,62,23,2,-2])
index=np.array(np.where(a>0))
for j in range (0,np.size(index)):
    X.append( S[index[j]] )
print(X)
```

But am getting an `IndexError` and I don't understand why. Can someone help?

Comment: Show the full traceback (with line numbers and the causing line of code)

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Right grammar is     X.append(S[index[0][j]])
but i still do not know what do you want to do

Comment: Theuse of `array(where(...` is odd.  So is the `np.size...`.  Print `index`, and make sure `j` is giving good values.

Answer (score 0):

You use an element from array "index" to decide which element to pull out of the S array

```
S[index[j]]
```

The value you are pulling (the value of index[j]) is pointing to a location that is not in S.

I suspect that your problem is that the np.where operation returns indices of `a` where the condition is true so you get a value of 10 in there which is one past the last index of S.  10 is the length of S.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [111]: j=0
In [112]: a=np.array([1,-8,-9,2,5,8,7,1,-5,-5,1])
     ...: S=np.array([4,8,9,8,9,55,6,62,23,2,-2])
     ...: 
In [113]: index=np.array(np.where(a>0))
In [114]: index
Out[114]: array([[ 0,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10]], dtype=int32)
In [115]: _.shape
Out[115]: (1, 7)
```

By wrapping the `where` in `np.array` you have created a (1,7) array.  Is that intentional?  Do you understand the consequences?

```
In [116]: np.size(index)
Out[116]: 7
```

Size gives the total number of elements.  Normally we use `shape`.

Indexing when `j=0` is ok:

```
In [117]: index[0]
Out[117]: array([ 0,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10], dtype=int32)
```

Except we've selected many values - the 1st row of a (1,7) array.

Advance `j` to 1, and we get the index error:

```
In [118]: index[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-f6a00d4fbf8f> in <module>()
----> 1 index[1]

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

That's trying to select the 2nd row.

Note the whole index error message - the index, the size, the axis.  All of that information is relevant and should have been included in your error message.

---

Step back to the `where`.  This produces a size 1 tuple (for 1 dim) with an array of 7 elements.

```
In [124]: index = np.where(a>0)
In [125]: index
Out[125]: (array([ 0,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10], dtype=int32),)
```

That tuple can be used directly for indexing.  For example the positive values of `a` are:

```
In [126]: a[index]
Out[126]: array([1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 1, 1])
```

And since `S` has the same shape, the corresponding elements are:

```
In [127]: S[index]
Out[127]: array([ 4,  8,  9, 55,  6, 62, -2])
```

No need to loop.

So

- pay attention to the whole error message
- print the problem values
- make sure you understand the indexing
- review docs of functions like `where`.